# Using ajax to pass a jquery string to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been working this for a while and have found numerous clues here on SO, but nothing is working yet.  I'm trying to create a dynamic drop down in a form that the user can add to by selecting an "add new" option which brings up a modal window in which the new option can be typed.  I use jquery to bring up the window and capture the input and ajax to (hopefully) post the text and retrieve it in php.  I see on the console that that the new option is captured in the javascript and ajax makes a post, but the post array is empty.

My code is all in the view.  When an "add new" is selected a modal window pops up in which text can be entered.  I want to capture the entered text in the view without submitting and display it in the updated options list.

```
                  <legend>Animal Info</legend>

                    <div class="control-group <?php if (form_error('animal_species')) { echo 'error'; } ?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Species</label>            
                        <div class="controls">

                            <?php                                                   # Add "Add New"
                            $options = $species + array('addnew' => 'Add New'); 
                            echo form_dropdown('animal_species', $options,
                                                set_value('animal_species', (isset($my_data->animal_species)) ? $my_data->animal_species: ''),
                                                'id = "animal_species"',
                                                'class', 'addnew');
                            echo form_error('animal_species', '<span class="help-inline">', '</span>');                                
                            ?> 

                        </div>
                    </div>                            
              <?php


                  if(isset($new_option))
                  {
                    $new_option = $_POST['new_option'];
                    $species = array($new_option => $new_option) + $species;
                    var_dump($new_option);
                  }

             ?>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      $('#upload_form option[value="addnew"]').click(function(){

          // Show modal window
          $('#add-new').modal('show');

          $('#add-new-submit').on('click', function(){

              // Get new option from text field
              var new_option = $('#add-new-text').val();
              console.log(new_option);

              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>main/upload_page",
                    data: {new_option:'new_option'}
                  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
                  });

              $('#add-new').modal('toggle');                              

           });

      //}); 
      });                 

  </script>

  <!-- add-new field -->
  <div class="modal small hide fade" id="add-new" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add-new-fieldLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="add-new-fieldLabel">Add New Field</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

          <p>Would you like to add a new item?</p>
          <input type="text" id="add-new-text" name="add-new" placeholder="Type the new option">

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-new-submit" name="add-new-submit"/>Add</button>
      </div>

 </div><!-- /add-new field -->
```

Right now the string new_options gets captured in the console but is NULL in the php, so ajax isn't posting for some reason.  Is this because I'm trying to update the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",                       
    url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>main/upload_page",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {new_option : 'new_option'}
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

if you're going to be able to access it with :

```
$_POST['new_option'];
```

in PHP.
Without keys, it would be just `$new_option = $_POST;` to get the string

Comment: Thanks so much for you response.  Putting the .fail here takes care of the ReferenceError, but putting in a key does not help.  ajax still does not post new_option to my view.  In my view I get a php notice "Undefined index: new_option" at the $_POST but the console shows that a new_option has been captured on the jQuery side.  It's apparently not getting posted by ajax however.

Answer (score 0):

since you are taking your posted value as `$_POST['new_option']`..you need to pass the data object as new_option in ajax...

try this

```
...
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",                       
         url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>main/upload_page",
         dataType: 'text',
         data:{'new_option':new_option},  //<---here                         
       });
       console.log(new_option);


.....
```